# What thread does the b-screw on a shimano rd-6400/6401 have?

Tags: shimano, derailleur, derailleur-rear

What thread does the b-screw on a shimano rd-6401 have?

I need to recut the thread but am not entirely sure if it's an M4 fine pitch or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have in front of me an RD-6500, Ultegra 9s rear derailleur. The B-screw is an M4 x .75 pitch x 12mm length. Looking at a couple older shimano derailleur's, it appears that the B-screw is also an M4.

Shimano's website has various technical documents, some of which are "exploded view" diagrams of the parts that make up the part. At the bottom is the list of the parts, and when it's a fastener, they often give the size and length of it. However, the exploded view of the RD-6400 does not have the size of the B adjust bolt. [Here is the EV](https://si.shimano.com/#/en/EV/RD-6500) of the RD-6500 which does list the B-screw as an M4 x 10mm.

Comment: To be clear, the part number is the same for rd-6400, rd-1056, rd-6500 and others , 5110501, so it should be exact same m4x10 bolt for all parts using that bolt.

Comment: Good call noting the same part number, @thelawnet.  I've used that comparison to see whether a couple different shadow derailleurs utilize the same standard mount bracket as well as for determining if chainring bolts were the same over a couple models.  Simply didn't dawn on me in this instance